# How to make a custom sklearn transformer for time series?

Tags: python, pandas, class, scikit-learn, time-series

I have a pandas Series object with a datetime index representing my time series y.

I model this time series by taking as independent variables, X, the previous 'p' steps of the series. So X is a pandas dataframe with a datetime index whose columns are shifts of y.

I usually see transformers in sklearn applied on both y and X, but in my case I don't have an X yet, I want to create it out of y and then have it be used by the subsequent 'fit' methods of the pipeline.

Here I write a custom transformer to generate X:

```
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline

class FeatureGenerator(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):

    #p stants for the number of step
    def __init__(self, p):
        self._p = p


    def fit(self):
        return self


    def transform(self, y):

        X = pd.concat([y.shift(+ i) for i in range(self._p)],axis=1)

        return X
```

And here I try to put this feature generator into a pipeline

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

feature_gen = FeatureGenerator(p = 4)
clf = LinearRegression()

pipeline= Pipeline(steps = [('feature_gen', feature_gen),
                            ('clf', LinearRegression())])
pipeline.fit(ts)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### List of the corrections

I added several changes to .make your pipeline work:

- First, for your transformer to be valid, it needs to have a `fit` method that takes the same parameters than the your `clf.fit` (btw, clf usually stands for classifier, which is misleading when it really is a linear regression..). In this case, given it is a linear regression, it takes `X,y` as parameters. Hence, you need to add these to your transformer as well.
- Second, you need to shift your `y` values even further because otherwise, you will allow data leakage, meaning you will insert the actual y value into the features, which is why I corrected this line

  ```
  pd.concat([X.shift(+ i) for i in range(self._p)],axis=1)
  ```

  to this

  ```
  pd.concat([X.shift(+ i) for i in range(1,self._p+1)],axis=1)
  ```
- Third, this will necessarily cause the appearance of NA's in the first `p` observations, which you may want to discard. I just added `fillna(0)` to get rid of the problem from a code perspective.
- Fourth, given that `LinearRegression()` needs to be fitted with an X and a y, you need to provide both to the pipeline. The way the transformer is set, `ts` plays both the role of `X`, which then gets lagged, and `y`.

### Wrapping it up

Once you put all these things together, you have:

```
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline

class FeatureGenerator(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):

    #p stants for the number of step
    def __init__(self, p):
        self._p = p


    def fit(self, X, y):
        return self


    def transform(self, X): #This X is in reality going to be the "y"
        X1 = pd.concat([X.shift(+ i) for i in range(1,self._p+1)],axis=1)
        return X1.fillna(0)
```

You can then try out your transformer like this:

```
feature_gen = FeatureGenerator(p = 4)
feature_gen.transform(ts)
```

And then use it in the pipeline like this:

```
feature_gen = FeatureGenerator(p = 4)
linreg = LinearRegression()

pipeline= Pipeline(steps = [('feature_gen', feature_gen), ('reg', 
linreg)])
pipeline.fit(ts,ts)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I will run this soon and accept your answer.

Comment: Glad it helped!